# How can I make a velocity system in python?

Tags: python

Im new to python and here is my code and error

### CODE

```
from processing import *

global XVel
Speed = 2
XVel = 0

def keyPressed(XVel):
  print(keyboard.key)

  if keyboard.key == "a":
    XVel = XVel + 0 - Speed
  elif keyboard.key == "d":
    XVel = XVel + Speed

run(XVel)
```

### ERROR

TypeError: keyPressed() takes exactly 1 arguments (0 given) on line 15 in main.py

### Task

Im trying to make a text velocity system and the code should be self expenetory for some

I tried to write it in none code terms:

Get keyboard

get the variable called XVel

set speed to 2
set xvel to 0

when a key is pressed
print the key that is pressed

```
if key is a
    set xvel to xvel + 0 - speed
else if key is d
    set xvel to xvel + speed
```

actually run everthing (I think)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you need to pass an argument to the function keyPressed when calling it. Since you have defined XVel as a global variable, you can remove the parameter XVel from the function definition, and simply reference the global variable inside the function using the global keyword.

```
import processing

global XVel
Speed = 2
XVel = 0

def keyPressed():
  global XVel
  print(keyboard.key)

  if keyboard.key == "a":
    XVel = XVel + 0 - Speed
  elif keyboard.key == "d":
    XVel = XVel + Speed

processing.run()
```

This should fix the error and allow you to run the code as expected.